# How to transform face mesh?

Tags: 3d, texture, mesh, model, 3dtexture

We can use ARcore to create custom textures and 3D models for Augmented Faces, like the augmentation of a Fox ears. But aside from augmenting 3D objects, can we "transform" facemesh, for instance to make a filter that makes eyes smaller or nose bigger and change the whole face? If so, how?

It doesn't have to be ARcore, any other free SDK would be fine.

```
Collection<AugmentedFace> faces = session.getAllTrackables(AugmentedFace.class);
//....


  if (face.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {

    // UVs and indices can be cached as they do not change during the session.

    FloatBuffer uvs = face.getMeshTextureCoordinates();

    ShortBuffer indices = face.getMeshTriangleIndices();

    // Center and region poses, mesh vertices, and normals are updated each frame.

    Pose facePose = face.getCenterPose();

    FloatBuffer faceVertices = face.getMeshVertices();

    FloatBuffer faceNormals = face.getMeshNormals();

    // Render the face using these values with OpenGL.

  }

}
```

[image: face transformation]

I tried the Fox ear example to augment a 3D model on the face. But not sure how to change the actual face like in the image.